# Unity: spawning enemies works but they are not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

[image: Unity workspace]

I'm busy with creating a school project where I need to integrate wave spawners.
For now, I used this video as an example and implemented it in my project.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0SBfDFn2Bs

Everything is spawning fine and I also get my debug logs. The main problem is: I can't see my enemies. (not John Cena guys hahah, in that case it would be logic ;) )

I'm new to Unity and I like the interface and workflow but I have a lot to learn. I hope someone can help me out! :)

Source WaveSpawner.cs:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class WaveSpawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public enum SpawnState { SPAWNING, WAITING, COUNTING };
 
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Wave
    {
        public string name;
        public Transform enemy;
        public int count;
        public float rate;
    }
 
    public Wave[] waves;
    private int nextWave = 0;
    public int NextWave
    {
        get { return nextWave + 1; }
    }
 
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
 
    public float timeBetweenWaves = 5f;
    private float waveCountdown;
    public float WaveCountdown
    {
        get { return waveCountdown; }
    }
 
    private float searchCountdown = 1f;
 
    private SpawnState state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
    public SpawnState State
    {
        get { return state; }
    }
 
    void Start()
    {
        if (spawnPoints.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No spawn points referenced.");
        }
 
        waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        if (state == SpawnState.WAITING)
        {
            if (!EnemyIsAlive())
            {
                WaveCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
 
        if (waveCountdown <= 0)
        {
            if (state != SpawnState.SPAWNING)
            {
                StartCoroutine( SpawnWave ( waves[nextWave] ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            waveCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
 
    void WaveCompleted()
    {
        Debug.Log("Wave Completed!");
 
        state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
        waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;
 
        if (nextWave + 1 > waves.Length - 1)
        {
            nextWave = 0;
            Debug.Log("ALL WAVES COMPLETE! Looping...");
        }
        else
        {
            nextWave++;
        }
    }
 
    bool EnemyIsAlive()
    {
        searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (searchCountdown <= 0f)
        {
            searchCountdown = 1f;
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
 
    IEnumerator SpawnWave(Wave _wave)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning Wave: " + _wave.name);
        state = SpawnState.SPAWNING;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < _wave.count; i++)
        {
            SpawnEnemy(_wave.enemy);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1f/_wave.rate );
        }
 
        state = SpawnState.WAITING;
 
        yield break;
    }
 
    void SpawnEnemy(Transform _enemy)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning Enemy: " + _enemy.name);
 
        Transform _sp = spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
        Instantiate(_enemy, _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
    }
 
}
```

[image: Unity debug]

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your [2D Layer Sorting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html)

Comment: Hey @derHugo I got the layer on 7 as the player sprite. So the player is visible and the bat, not.

Comment: In the image you posted I can see the bat ... Should there be something else?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see is you're also changing the Z position of the bat. Generally you would not want to do that in a 2D game cause it can go behind stuff as is happening there. In the code I did notice that you are using random points in the world so you would want to check the Z position of those points and change them to 0 or 1.Here's the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ9IY.png) of what you need to change on the points! Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey my friend, I changed it to 0 and 1, but it still doesn't work. It still gives the debugs but I don't see them.